# What is the WebSphere Application Server APAR for AIX error code CWNBV0005W

Tags: websphere

I found an APAR I need for WebSphere Application Server to fix error code CWNBV0005W, but it is for ZOS:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM85921

I am looking for the same patch for IBM AIX but cannot find it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's no other APAR. It looks like this APAR was discovered by a user who happened to be on WAS for z/OS.  This fix should be present in any server w/ maintenance from the last several years if you really have the same cause.